# CFExchangemail Error - Appointment cannot be cast as EmailMessage

Tags: coldfusion, exchangewebservices

We have a ColdFusion scheduled task that runs periodically to "harvest" emails out of an Exchange inbox.  It has run well for quite a while.  Recently we're getting this error:

microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Appointment cannot be cast to microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage

The error appears to be getting generated within the CFExchangemail tag, itself.  Our guess is that something in the inbox is cast as an Appointment rather than mail but in looking directly at the Inbox on exchange we see nothing amiss.  We've cleared out the whole inbox and calendar of this account but the error continues.

This appears to only affect the Inbox.  I can query other folders using CFExchange with no problems.

Any ideas?

Here's the tag call where the error occurs (nothing special):

```
<cfexchangemail
action = "get"
name = "FindAccountMail"
connection = "cxn">

<cfexchangefilter name="Folder" value="Inbox">

<cfexchangefilter name="MessageType" value="Mail">
```

Comment: Can you post your full version and the complete trace? Maybe I haven't used cfexchangemail, but someone else has with that version has seen the issue before.

Comment: You will have different types in the Inbox eg a Calendar invitations won't be returned as an EmailMessage. The basetype is EWS is ItemType so if your expected everything in the Inbox to the MessageType the there is bug in the library your using.

Comment: Today it has mysteriously started working again?  This is not the first time this has happened, though.  When it occurs again I will post the full trace.

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion?